# Quickest way to select rows from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe df with millions of rows, and columns A1,..., AN

What is the quickest way to select rows such that `df['A1']==30`?

Edit: there are at least three methods:

1. Method 1. `df[(df['A1']==30)]`
2. Method 2. `df.query('A1==30')`
3. Method 3. Do `df = df.set_index(A1)` once; then `df.loc[30]` (or `df.loc[x]` for all x values we try to locate in the column A1)

What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 8):

50 Million rows and 52 columns

```
from string import ascii_letters

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50, size=(50000000, 52)), columns=list(ascii_letters))
```

Variety of methods

```
%timeit df[df.B == 30]
%timeit df[df.B.values == 30]
%timeit df.query('B == 30')

1 loop, best of 3: 31.4 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 31.6 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 27.1 s per loop
```

Use `numexpr`

```
import numexpr as ne

%%timeit
B = df.B.values
df[ne.evaluate('B == 30')]

1 loop, best of 3: 22.8 s per loop
```

Or reconstruct the whole thing with `numpy` slicing in addition to `numexpr`

```
%%timeit
B = df.B.values
mask = ne.evaluate('B == 30')
pd.DataFrame(df.values[mask], df.index[mask], df.columns)

1 loop, best of 3: 21.4 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [Enhancing Performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html). From here you will see that you get significant speed ups from,

```
df.query('A1==30')
```

There is more information in that link but I am sure this is the easiest to implement.